# Selenium Python3 scrape text outside of a tag from Chrome

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape text outside of a tag.  I am using Python3.7 and I tried both Selenium and BeautifulSoup4.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<br>
<span class="label">Max. Allowable Residential FAR:</span>
 10
<br>
```

I also took a picture of it in case I didn't copy the HTML correctly:

[image]

WHAT I WANT TO GET IS THE TEXT `10` (in the gray area in the picture above)

I tried using ***Selenium*** by xpath, here is my code:

```
res_far_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ext-gen376"]/div/div[6]/ul/li[7]/text()[2]')
```

I copied the xpath DIRECTLY from the HTML and it does not scrape the `10`.

The Selenium error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="ext-gen376"]/div/div[6]/ul/li[7]/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

I also tried using ***BeautifulSoup***, and here is my code:

```
attributes = html_soup.find('span',{'class':'Max. Allowable Residential FAR:'}).next_sibling
```

The BeautifulSoup error message is:

```
File "far_1.py", line 101, in <module>
    attributes = html_soup.find('span',{'class':'Max. Allowable Residential FAR:'}).next_sibling
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'
```

At this point, I am a beginner and only know something about Selenium and BeautifulSoup, so I would appreciate it if the solution uses those tools.

All help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a larger section of the html code you're looking at? Or a link?

Comment: Jack I couldn't get more of the HTML code to copy directly into the message, so I edited the picture that shows the code, I will try to get the actual HTML code into my message shortly.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you couldn't find a value by typing text value for `class` value in find statement in BeautifulSoup.

So I've defined a `label` for the `class` value and added a text value comparison syntax like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/text.html')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
attributes = html_soup.find('span', {'class':'label'}, text = 'Max. Allowable Residential FAR:').next_sibling
print(attributes)
# output
# 
# 10
#
```

Here is `text.html`

```
<html><head></head><body>
<br>

<span class="label">Max. Allowable Residential FAR:</span>
 10
<br>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you Roy, but I just tried it and I get the same error:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'.  Am I not importing a module that I need?  I have pretty much imported everything I can think of that would be relevant

Comment: I wrote one `html` statement based on the code you gave and tested it. It worked fine without any problems here. I don't know what's the difference with you.

Comment: Thank you again Roy, but now I get this error:     elem = requests.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: You should not do this `elem = requests.find_element_by_xpath("//*")`" and so do `elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")`.  please use `selenium driver`, not `requests`. Based on your code, you modify `elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*")` like this

Comment: I changed the code to make it easier to understand. Check out the new code.

Comment: Yes, except "broswer" is what I am using to get to the website, and it throughout my code like this:  browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.oasisnyc.net/map.aspx')

Comment: Hey Roy it worked thank you very much.  I see what you did there, it's perfect.  Thank you again!